# Email GmailBackground Security Exception

Tags: android

I am using the GMAIL Background library located at the following:

https://github.com/yesidlazaro/GmailBackground

I am getting a `java.lang.SecurityException` when i use a Samsung Galaxy S8 Android 8.0 with the code. I get the crash log below. Could anyone tell me if they have had similar issues or if there is something new in the Galaxy S8 that i need to account for in the code? Thank you.

```
Samsung Galaxy S8 (dreamqltesq). Android 8.0
Java.lang.SecurityException:

1. at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.Java:1967)
2. at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1913)
3. at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zzb (Unknown Source:10)
4. at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcdx.zza (Unknown Source:9)
5. at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcea.zza (Unknown Source:41)
6. at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzceh.zza (Unknown Source:5)
7. at com.google.android.gms.location.zzi.zzb (Unknown Source:ll)
8. at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzd.zzb (Unknown Source:8)
9. at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzb.zza (Unknown Source)
10. at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.zzb (Unknown Source:9)
11. at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.zza (Unknown Source:17)
12. at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbp.handleMessage (Unknown Source:378)
13. at android.os.Handler.dispatchHessage (Handler.Java:101)
14. at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.Java:164)
15. at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Comment: Looks like you do not have a certain permission.. In android 8, you're not allowed to create background services anymore, perhaps that's the error, but it'd be easier to determine if you could use a deobfuscated stack trace

Comment: Thank you the_dani. I am new to android. Could you tell me how to create a deobfuscated stack trace?

Comment: Also, I am not sure which permission is causing the error. would the following be the best way to request all permissions? private static final int REQUESTCODE_PERMISSION = 301;      
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS,                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, REQUESTCODE_PERMISSION);

Comment: Well you do not provide code so I can only guess how you implement it.. I think you're using a service and request data in background, so you need to declare Permission FOREGROUND_SERVICE in manifest, and you've to start the GMAIL Library in foreground.